# C# - How to write Editor Script which shows currently attached Android Devices and put them on the list in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a tool on the Unity with C# language, which will help build and run programs easier and I can choose which phones I want to perform, but I've encountered a few problems.

1. For a long time, I tried to get all the connected phones in the Editor window until I eventually succeeded, but they are only displayed on the Console window. I have no idea how to put them in the Custom Editor window. I also tried to output only the name of the phone but did not get it - it outputs the ID, the name, and etc.
2. If you explain how to make the first point, the next question is - how to put them in the list precisely so that I can optionally choose on which phones I want to just build the program and on which I want to build and run. I would do this with checkboxes. I tried to put them on the list, but again unsuccessful.
3. How to create and describe TextField where I can write additional flags when installing/running on the phone?

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class DeviceClass
{
    public static string model;
    public static bool enableDevice = false;
}

public class Builder : EditorWindow
{

    public string[] options = new string[] { "Android", "iOS", "Both platform", "Install and Run" };
    public int index = 0;
    private static Process proc;
    public static string MyPhones;
    List<string> Listas = new List<string>();

    //private static ProcessStartInfo psi; 

    [MenuItem("Editor/Builderis")]

    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<Builder>("Builderis");
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Select platform", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(index, options);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Build Project"))
            InstantiatePrimitive();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
        {
            List<DeviceClass> deviceclass = new List<DeviceClass>();
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            psi.FileName = "C:/Android/platform-tools/adb.exe";
            psi.Arguments = "devices -l";
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.OutputDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit();
            foreach (var x in Listas)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Listas[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    static void AndroidBuild()
    {
        BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptionsAndroid = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        buildPlayerOptionsAndroid.scenes = new[] { "Assets/Scenes/Main.unity" };
        buildPlayerOptionsAndroid.locationPathName = "Test1";
        buildPlayerOptionsAndroid.target = BuildTarget.Android;
        buildPlayerOptionsAndroid.options = BuildOptions.None;
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptionsAndroid);
    }

    static void iOSBuild()
    {
        BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptionsiOS = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        buildPlayerOptionsiOS.scenes = new[] { "Assets/Scenes/Main.unity" };
        buildPlayerOptionsiOS.locationPathName = "Test2";
        buildPlayerOptionsiOS.target = BuildTarget.iOS;
        buildPlayerOptionsiOS.options = BuildOptions.None;
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptionsiOS);
    }

    public static void InstallAndroid()
    {
        // Run the game (Process class from System.Diagnostics).
        //string fullPath = Application.dataPath.Replace("/Assets", "/") + "_BUILDS/android/build.apk";
        //string appid = PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier;
        proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Android/platform-tools/adb.exe"; // replace with your adb exe path
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-d install -r u.apk";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }

    public static void LaunchAndroid()
    {
        // Run the game (Process class from System.Diagnostics).
        //string fullPath = "u.apk";
        string appid = PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier;
        proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Android/platform-tools/adb.exe"; // replace with your adb exe path
        //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell am start -a " + appid + "u.apk";//" -n /com.unity.jte";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell monkey -p " + appid + " -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1";
        proc.Start();
    }

    static void p_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Manipulate received data here
        MyPhones = e.Data.ToString();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(MyPhones);
        // UnityEngine.Debug.Log(MyPhones);
        if (e.Data.Contains("device") && !e.Data.Contains("List"))
        {
            int index = MyPhones.LastIndexOf("model:") + 6;
            if (index > 0)
            {
                MyPhones = MyPhones.Substring(index);
                MyPhones = MyPhones.Substring(0, MyPhones.IndexOf("device"));
                //Listas[index].Add(MyPhones);
            }
        }

        // if no devices, then there will be only "List of devices attached: "
    }

    void InstantiatePrimitive()
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                AndroidBuild();
                break;
            case 1:
                iOSBuild();
                break;
            case 2:
                AndroidBuild();
                iOSBuild();
                break;
            case 3:
                InstallAndroid();
                LaunchAndroid();
                break;
            case 4:
                //p_DataReceived(PSI, P);
                break;
            default:
                //Debug.LogError("Unrecognized Option");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For (1) If it doesn't output "only the name of the phone", what does it output? (2) Listas[index].Add(MyPhones); wont work, it's simply Listas.Add(MyPhones). Also see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Toggle.html 
(3) and.. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.TextField.html

Comment: Also, add your console logs, so we can actually tell what the output is like

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios It outputs this - List of devices attached
ce081718f57ad4a40d7e   device product:greatqlteue model:SM_N950U1 device:greatqlteue transport_id:1
By the way, I know how to create TextField and etc. but I do not know how to create that function in TextField, that I could write additional flags.